# How to delete lines which contains only numbers in python?

Tags: python, file, numbers, text-files

I have a large text file in Python. Firstly, I want to read the text then, delete lines which have only numbers. Then, I open a new text file and write with my changes.

If the line contains numbers and strings, I want to keep them. I tried with isdigit and regex but I couldn't...

e.g. I tried: but it deletes all lines that contain numbers.

```
    if not all(line.isdigit() for line in text_data):
```

---

new question:

line1: 324 4234 23456

if I have a line which contains numbers and space only like line1, how I skip them to my new text file?

Comment: It depends what you do inside the `if`. Do you write the line to the file or do you skip the line?

Comment: Also why do you loop over all lines again *for each line in the file*?

Comment: I want to write if it contains both numbers and strings. If the line contains only numbers, I need the skip them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strip whitespace from the line before checking if it is all numbers.

```
for line in text_data:
    if line.strip().isdigit():
        # do what is required for a line with all numbers
    else:
        # do what is required for an alphanumeric line
```

Comment: This is a better answer! I'm out! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to read the file, filter it if line is not a digit, then write it to a new file:

```
with open('old.txt') as old, open('new.txt', 'w') as new:
    for line in filter(lambda text: not text.strip().isnumeric(), old): new.write(line)
```